# How can I create a new column to track any changes between two columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am comparing two excel files using pandas and monitoring certain columns to identify any changes that were made.  Currently, I am creating a boolean column to see if column A in df1 is equal to column A in df2, which gives me a new column of True/False values.  I do the same thing for column B in both the new and old dataframe. I am having trouble creating a "master change" column that will tell me if a change was made in either or both of the columns I am checking.

Right now, my "master change" column checks to see if the boolean column checking column A and B are equal.  If there is a change in only 1 column (ColA = True, ColB = False), my "master change column correctly marks it as False, so I can later identify that as a row that needs to be updated.
However, when there is a change in BOTH columns (ColA=False, ColB=False), my "master change" column marks that row as True, as expected.

```
old_data = [[1, 'red', 'short'], [2, 'blue', 'medium'],[3, 'green', 'long']]  
new_data = [[1, 'red', 'short'], [2, 'green', 'long'],[3, 'green', 'short']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(old_data, columns=['ID_num', 'original_color', 'original_length'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['ID_num', 'current_color', 'current_length'])

df_combined = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID_num', how='left')

df_combined['color_change'] = df_combined['current_color'] == df_combined['original_color']
df_combined['length_change'] = df_combined['current_length'] == df_combined['original_length']
df_combined['master_change'] = df_combined['color_change'] == df_combined['length_change']

df_combined['master_change']
```

This gives me a "master_change" column value of:

True
True
False

How can I get pandas to give me a value of False in the "master_change" column if BOTH the color and length values have changed? (i.e., False, False --> False)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the boolean operator `OR`, which gives `True` if any of the operands is `True`. With pandas series you can use it like this:

```
df_combined['master_change'] = df_combined['color_change'] | df_combined['length_change']
```

If you want the column to be `True` only if both are `True` you can use the `AND` operator:

```
df_combined['master_change'] = df_combined['color_change'] & df_combined['length_change']
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, the “&” and “|” symbols is what I was missing!!  I was playing around in the terminal with things like “True and False” and “False and False” but couldn’t figure out how to use “and” with pandas. That works exactly like I wanted, thank you so much!!